# Only "Recently Viewed" option for list view

Tags: list, view

It seems my only option to view leads is "Recently Viewed". How can I change this?[image]

Comment: What is your user profile?

Comment: I'm an admin, I'm the sole user of Salesforce at my company.

Answer (score 0):

Below are checkpoints.

1. Possibility of Sharing settings changes made by you or other user. If 'Share list view with groups of users' is selected and if you do not have users in group then it might be private mode.

[image]

2. It might got deleted accidentally by you or someone.
3. If you still see same, workaround would be creating new list views (All Open Leads, My Unread Leads etc.,).